# Оптимизация функции поиска предыдущего/следующего элемента массива

Tags: массивы, javascript, оптимизация

В процессе самообучения программированию на javascript, поставил себе такую задачу:
Пользователь задает исходный массив, заполненный некоторыми значениями.
Необходимо найти следующий (или предыдущий) элемент массива, относительно элемента, указанного пользователем.
В качестве дополнения необходимо реализовать поддержку "зацикливания".
*Интересуют только массивы и только строгое сравнение.

Варианты реализации php-функций в php_js я видел.*

**Пример для наглядности, что я хотел получить в итоге:**

```
var arr = [1, 4, 5, 7];
console.log(next(1, arr));          // 4
console.log(next(7, arr));          // false
console.log(next(7, arr, 'cycle')); // 1
console.log(next('bar', arr));      // false
```

**Поставленную задачу я [решил](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/xR4nd/) следующим образом:**

```
function arraySearch(needle, haystack) {
    for (var i = 0; i < haystack.length; ++i) {
        if (haystack[i] === needle) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

function nextElem(needle, haystack, cycle) {
    cycle = typeof (cycle) === 'undefined' ? false : !! cycle;
    var key = arraySearch(needle, haystack, true);
    if (key > -1) {
        /* Вышли за правый предел массива? */
        if (++key > (haystack.length - 1)) {
            /* Если "зацикливание" установлено, возвращается первый элемент */
            return (cycle && haystack[0]);
        } else {
            return haystack[key];
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function prevElem(needle, haystack, cycle) {
    cycle = typeof (cycle) === 'undefined' ? false : !! cycle;
    var key = arraySearch(needle, haystack, true);
    if (key > -1) {
        /* Вышли за левый предел массива? */
        if (--key < 0) {
            /* Если "зацикливание" установлено, возвращается последний элемент */
            return (cycle && haystack[haystack.length - 1]);
        } else {
            return haystack[key];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Теперь вопросы:**
1) Почему такое условие "**true && 4**" возвращает 4, а не 1 или true? Это стандартное поведение javascript? Где об этом можно почитать? После php такой результат был полезной неожиданностью.
2) Что бы именно вы исправили в данном решении задачи и почему? Может быть, вы решили бы задачу иначе? Если да, то как (любопытство)?

Обращаюсь к сообществу не за готовым решением (задача решена), а скорее за code-review.

Comment: Вы удивитесь ещё больше, но 4 && true - это буленово и равно true :)

Comment: @KoVadim, выходит, писать так:  

    return (true && 4);  

плохая практика?

Comment: если так, как Вы написали - да, плохо. Потому что это константа:)

Но в любом случае, смешивание разнотипных данных в одном выражении, где должны быть однотипные - плохая практика. Такое применяется только в с/с++, так как это часто бывает сильно платформеннозависимо. Лучше написать так

    true && 4 != 0

это однозначно и понятно.

Comment: @VenZell Пожалуйста, не применяйте `форматирование` без дела. Это форматирование предназначено для *идентификаторов в коде*, а не для любых слов. Названия сред разработки, языков программирования и т.п. — не идентификаторы в коде, они никак не должны выделяться.

Comment: @Athari, хорошо, я учту на будущее

Comment: За компанию к синониму [tag:регулярные-выражения] ← [tag:regexp] можно добавить ещё [tag:регулярные-выражения] ← [tag:regex].

Comment: Он уже предложен для метки [tag:regexp]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function next(number, array, cycle) {
    var index = array.indexOf(number);

    if(index != -1) {
        if(index+1 == array.length) {
            if(cycle) {
                return array[0];
            }

            return false;
        }
        else {
            return array[index+1];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

И:

```
true && 4
```

Типа:

```
if (true) {
  4;
}

console.log(true && 4);
console.log(false && 4);

for(var i=0; i < 10;i++) {
     i % 2 && console.log(i);
}
```